# In a TFS 2010 build summary, how do I a show a link to the logs from a custom MSBuild task?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

In my TFS 2010 build definition, I call MSBuild on my own custom my.targets MSBuild project. It does all the compilation, testing, etc. that I need. Its log file is specified, as is a log drop location, and the log appears properly in that place. However I can't see it in the TFS Build Summary report. The "View Log File" link is grayed out. It seemed to work when the project I was building was a ".sln" file. What magic voodoo is baked deep in to the heart of the common MSBuild files to make this log link work properly, and how can I reproduce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find your answer in these posts from Jason Prickett:

1. [TFS2010 – Changing The Way Build Information IS Displayed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2009/12/22/tfs2010-changing-the-way-build-information-is-displayed.aspx)
2. [TFS2010 – Customizing the Build Details View – Summary View](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/08/09/tfs2010-customizing-the-build-details-view-summary-view.aspx)

Comment: That's the best answer I was able to find so far as well. It's a shame to use a custom assembly and all the work that implies just to show a link in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Important to note is that the MSBuild Log File will only appear if you enabled inside the build definition to copy output to the Drop Folder. If that option is disabled, the link will not appear in the build log view.